# C# .Net 2.0 My Encoding works on Windows XP and Vista but not Windows 7

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a .Net 2.0 app that uses UnicodeEncoding.Unicode when saving to a file when the data contains foreign characters this works fine on Windows XP and Vista but not on Windows 7, on Windows 7 I get a question marks ???? in the file (text file) instead of the correct characters. Any ideas where I should look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your Windows 7 machine doesn't happen to have the proper font installed for displaying those particular unicode characters, while your XP and Vista boxes do have the correct font installed.

Or it's possible that the applications you're using to view the text files are different.